# str2date php or mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filtered data in table by deleting "last two hours" from now. I am importing data by uploading csv that I cant change and using 3 fields only. one of fields is datetime but imported as string - 05 Dec 2018 22:20
I need somehow calculate last two hours form now and delete them from table. I tried str to date in mysql but keep getting error invalid datetime value, I tried strtotime in php but same..
It is not important how is deleted is it at csv import itslef I am using this for import

```
<?php

include('connection.php');
$con = getdb();

if(isset($_POST["Import"])){        
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",");
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $getData = str_replace("'","''",$getData);
            $sql = "INSERT into test2 (type_ID,name,Last_Contact) values ('".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."','".$getData[12]."')";
            // $sql = "INSERT into test2  (date) = STR_TO_DATE(Last_Contact, '%d %b %Y %H:%i')";

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            var_dump(mysqli_error_list($con));
            //exit();
            if(!isset($result))
            {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                           alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                           window.location = \"index.php\"
                     </script>";        

                // $sql = "INSERT into test2  (date) = STR_TO_DATE(Last_Contact, '%d %b %Y %H:%i')"; this part if unmasked returns error
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: --update and I belive I would delete easily if I would have proper datetime

Comment: Indenting your code properly goes a very long way.

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into the SQL string. Then you wouldn't need to double the quotes.

Comment: You shouldn't be inserting the date with a separate query. That will put the date into a different row from the other fields.

Comment: @Barmar i dont mind that, even better. I tested query you suggested but I keep getting errors  Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /var  Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /var

Comment: I forgot the `$con` argument to `mysqli_prepare()`.

Comment: @bramar thank you, works as charm.. now I can continue to remove certain rows from table based on time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a prepared statement. The problem is that you're not calling `STR_TO_DATE()` on the string you just inserted into the table. Your second `INSERT` query doesn't have any relationship to the previous one, so it can't access the `Last_Contact` column that you just inserted.

You should call `STR_TO_DATE()` on the string that you've read from the CSV, not a table column, since you need to insert this in the same row.

You should also use a prepared statement rather than concatenating variables.

```
$type_id = $name = $date = null;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO test2 (type_ID, name, Last_Contact, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, STR_TO_DATE(?, '%d %b %Y %H:%i'))");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $type_id, $name, $date, $date);
while ($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) {
    $type_id = $getData[3];
    $name = $getData[4];
    $date = $getData[12];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```